# Need to write SQL Server query to return sum of unique values (based on one column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
Supplier    Reference       Description      Total    
--------------------------------------------------
smiths      BP657869510L    NULL             42
smiths      BP657869510L    NULL             42
smiths      BP654669510L    No. 5621         13
smiths      BP654669510L    No. 5621         13
corrigan    15:51           Order 23542      23
corrigan    15:51           Order 23542      23
williams    14015           Block B          19
williams    14015           Block B          19
```

I would like to write a T-SQL query to

- return the list of transactions with each supplier, eliminating duplicate entries based on the `Reference` column.
- return the total sum of transactions with each supplier, again eliminating duplicate entries based on the `Reference` column.

So the results I would want to return based on the data above would be

```
    Supplier    Reference       Description      Total    
    ---------------------------------------------------
    smiths      BP657869510L    NULL             42
    smiths      BP654669510L    No. 5621         13
    corrigan    15:51           Order 23542      23
    williams    14015           Block B          19
```

and for the second requirement:

```
    Supplier    Total  
    ---------------------  
    smiths      55
    corrigan    23
    williams    19
```

Is this possible? Please note that values in other columns may differ even though the `Reference` column contains the same value. It doesn't matter if this occurs, I am only concerned with rows which contain a distinct or unique `Reference` value.

Comment: Your explanations are confusing. Is it possible to have different `Reference` for each `Supplier`? What if there are different `Reference` with the same `Total`, do you still want only a single row considered? If the `Description` differs, which one to choose, randomly?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have different `Reference` for each `Supplier` - I demonstrated this by placing entries for the `Supplier` 'smiths' in my sample table with different `Reference` entries. I want each row with a unique `Reference` to be considered whether the amount is the same or not. If the `Description` differs in rows where the `Reference` is the same I don't have a preference as to which one is chosen, but ideally I would like to return one of them.

Comment: @james please update the result data for the second question. atm it is misleading

Comment: The result data for the second question reads as intended. I want the sum total of all unique transactions (based on the `Reference` column) with each `Supplier`

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @tempData table
(
    supplier nvarchar(20),
    reference nvarchar (20),
    xDescription nvarchar(20),
    total int
);

insert into @tempData
select 'smiths',      'BP657869510L'    ,NULL,             42 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP657869510L'    ,NULL,             42 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP654669510L'    ,'No. 5621',         13 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP654669510L'    ,'No. 5621',         13 union all
select 'corrigan',    '15:51'           ,'Order 23542',      23 union all
select 'corrigan',    '15:51'           ,'Order 23542',      23 union all
select 'williams',    '14015'           ,'Block B',          19 union all
select 'williams',    '14015'           ,'Block B',          19
;

select distinct x.supplier,
SUM(X.total)OVER(PARTITION BY x.supplier )As Total from 
(Select a.supplier,a.reference,a.xDescription,a.total from @tempData a
GROUP BY a.supplier,a.reference,a.xDescription,a.total) X 
GROUP BY x.supplier,X.total
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to make a slight adjustment to this query but it lead me to the answer to my second question (ie. the total sum of transactions). This is the query which worked: select distinct x.supplier,
SUM(X.total)OVER(PARTITION BY x.supplier)As Total from 
(Select a.supplier,a.reference,a.description,a.total from @tempData a
GROUP BY a.supplier,a.reference,a.description,a.total) X 
GROUP BY x.supplier,x.reference,X.total

Comment: How about my answer LOL. Dude i should at least a vote up, mohan111 is using my @tempdata query LOL.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment from the OP `Total` is always the same for `Reference`, but `Description` can change. `DISTINCT` is equivalent to a `GROUP BY` all the columns in the `SELECT`

To get the first requirement a distinct is enough, if it's possible to drop the `Description` column

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Supplier
     , Reference
     , Total
FROM   myTable
```

if it's not possible then a NULL, a MAX or something on the same line can be done, in the query below a `NULL` is returned if there are more then one values for the group, otherwise the single value is outputted

```
SELECT Supplier
     , Reference
     , Description = CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Description) > 1 THEN NULL
                          ELSE MAX(Description)
                     END
     , Total
FROM   myTable
GROUP BY Supplier, Reference, Total
```

To get the second the above query can be used as a `CTE` for the main query where a `GROUP BY` is added, in this case the `Description` columns is not needed so is dropped.

```
With dValue AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         Supplier
       , Reference
       , Total
  FROM   myTable
)
SELECT Supplier
     , SUM(Total) Total
FROM   dValue
GROUP BY Supplier
```

If you have a version of SQLServer where the `CTE` are not possible the first query can be used as a subquery to get the same result

```
SELECT Supplier
     , SUM(Total) Total
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Supplier, Reference, Total
        FROM   myTable) dValue
GROUP BY Supplier
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, just using a distinct (as in your first response) returns all rows where any of the columns is distinct. It will return rows where the Reference is the same if, for example, the description is slightly different. I only want rows where the Reference is distinct.

Comment: Apologies - it's possible that the Reference may be the same in 2 or more rows where other columns contain different values. Any suggestions for a query to only return rows where the Reference is distinct?

Comment: For my purposes the `Total` will be the same if the `Reference` is the same. The `Description` may be different.

Comment: Thank you, I had thought of dropping `Description` from your initial query but ideally I would like to return the `Description` column as well as the others for my first question. I see that your query with the rule returns NULL for `Description` if there is more than one unique `Description` value for a group - is there any way of returning the `Description` value accurately instead of returning NULL in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try below sql

assuming @tempData is your table name.

```
declare @tempData table
(
    supplier nvarchar(20),
    reference nvarchar (20),
    xDescription nvarchar(20),
    total int
);

insert into @tempData
select 'smiths',      'BP657869510L'    ,NULL,             42 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP657869510L'    ,NULL,             42 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP654669510L'    ,'No. 5621',         13 union all
select 'smiths',      'BP654669510L'    ,'No. 5621',         13 union all
select 'corrigan',    '15:51'           ,'Order 23542',      23 union all
select 'corrigan',    '15:51'           ,'Order 23542',      23 union all
select 'williams',    '14015'           ,'Block B',          19 union all
select 'williams',    '14015'           ,'Block B',          19
;

select 
    a.supplier
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
from @tempData a
group by a.supplier 
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
;

/*
supplier             reference            xDescription         total
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
corrigan             15:51                Order 23542          23
smiths               BP654669510L         No. 5621             13
smiths               BP657869510L         NULL                 42
williams             14015                Block B              19
*/


with cte as
(
select 
    a.supplier
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
from @tempData a
group by a.supplier 
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
) 
select 
    distinct c.supplier, sum(c.total) over(partition by c.supplier) as total
from cte c
;

/*
supplier             total
-------------------- -----------
corrigan             23
smiths               55
williams             19
*/
```

**UPDATE**

as requested, the aim for this query is to include Separate record that has the same supplier with different description: example supplier smith
Dense_Rank() will fulfill this request ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.90%29.aspx))

```
with cte as
(
select 
    a.supplier
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
    ,dense_rank() over(partition by a.supplier order by a.supplier, a.xDescription) as dRow
from @tempData a
group by a.supplier 
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
) 
select 
    distinct c.supplier, sum(c.total) over(partition by c.supplier,drow) as total
from cte c
;

/*
supplier             total
-------------------- -----------
corrigan             23
smiths               13
smiths               42
williams             19
*/
```

View All field

```
with cte as
(
select 
    a.supplier
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
    ,dense_rank() over(partition by a.supplier order by a.supplier, a.xDescription) as dRow
from @tempData a
group by a.supplier 
    , a.reference
    , a.xDescription
    , a.total
) 
select 
    distinct c.supplier, c.reference,c.xDescription, sum(c.total) over(partition by c.supplier,drow) as total
from cte c
;
```

Comment: This query returns all rows where any of the columns contains data which is distinct. It will return multiple rows where the `Reference` is the same if, for example, `Description` is slightly different in each row. I only want to return rows where value for `Reference` is distinct.

Comment: @james this query provide the result that you want for the first and second questions. Could you describe further the issue by adding more data sample? and pls also update the data result that u desire.

Comment: Thank you but if you change one of the values for `Description` in my table above to something unique your query will not return the result that I describe above.

Comment: check my update, the result has 2 SMiths because they have different Description. Pls Edit your question's result data. at the moment it is misleading