# SQL Server query to eliminate duplicates based on single column where another column may differ

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
Supplier        ReferenceID         Description        Total    
------------------------------------------------------------
smiths          BP657869510L        Order 67543         42
smiths          BP657869510L        Order 67543B        42
smiths          BP654669517L        No. 5621            13
smiths          BP654669517L        No. 56211           13
corrigan        15:51               Order 23542         23
corrigan        15:51               Order 235422        23
williams        14015               Block B             19
williams        14015               Block B2            19
```

I would like to write a T-SQL query to return the list of transactions with each supplier, eliminating duplicate entries based on the `ReferenceID` column. As you can see from the table, the `Description` value may be different in two columns with the same `ReferenceID` (due to data entry error). In this case, if possible, I would like to return one of these `Description` values (I don't care which one).

So the results I would want to return based on the data above would be (I picked the `Description` values randomly - I don't have a preference as to which one is returned as long as it is tied to the `ReferenceID` in the original table.)

```
    Supplier     ReferenceID        Description        Total    
    --------------------------------------------------------
    smiths       BP657869510L       Order 67543         42
    smiths       BP654669517L       No. 5621            13
    corrigan     15:51              Order 23542         23
    williams     14015              Block B             19
```

I realise this is quite complex but any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: use `GROUP BY Supplier, ReferenceID` and `MAX(Description)` in your select list

Comment: How do you want to handle total?

Comment: Isn't that the same of your last (still open) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505461/need-to-write-sql-server-query-to-return-sum-of-unique-values-based-on-one-colu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `GROUP BY ReferenceID`, if the rest is arbitrary/equal you can use `MAX` or `MIN`:

```
SELECT Supplier = MIN(Supplier),
       ReferenceID,        
       Description = MIN(Description),        
       Total = MIN(Total)
FROM dbo.Tablename
GROUP BY ReferenceID
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cbac/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Supplier
    ,ReferenceID
    ,MAX(Description) [Description]
    ,SUM(TOTAL) [TOTAL] --or MIN/MAX/AVG etc...
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Supplier
    ,ReferenceID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull one record per ReferenceID while maintaining the integrity of the record, then you can use dense_rank() like this.

```
WITH Table_CTE (Supplier, ReferenceID, Description, Total, RefRank) AS
(
  SELECT Supplier, ReferenceID, Description, Total,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ReferenceID ORDER BY Description) As RefRank
  FROM Table
)
SELECT Supplier, ReferenceID, Description, Total
FROM Table_CTE
WHERE RefRank = 1
```

Using GROUP BY as suggested by others might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE 
    ([Supplier] varchar(8), [ReferenceID] varchar(12), [Description] varchar(12), [Total] int)
;

INSERT INTO @TableName
    ([Supplier], [ReferenceID], [Description], [Total])
VALUES
    ('smiths', 'BP657869510L', 'Order 67543', 42),
    ('smiths', 'BP657869510L', 'Order 67543B', 42),
    ('smiths', 'BP654669517L', 'No. 5621', 13),
    ('smiths', 'BP654669517L', 'No. 56211', 13),
    ('corrigan', '15:51', 'Order 23542', 23),
    ('corrigan', '15:51', 'Order 235422', 23),
    ('williams', '14015', 'Block B', 19),
    ('williams', '14015', 'Block B2', 19)
;

;WITH CTE AS
(
Select distinct t.Supplier,tt.ReferenceID,t.[Description],Total
 from @TableName t
INNER JOIN 
(Select distinct MIN(Supplier)as r,ReferenceID,MIN([Description]) as k
 From @TableName
GROUP BY ReferenceID )tt
ON tt.ReferenceID = t.ReferenceID
AND t.Supplier = tt.r
AND t.Description = tt.k
GROUP BY t.Supplier,t.[Description],tt.ReferenceID,t.Total
)
Select C.Supplier,C.ReferenceID,C.Description,SUM(C.Total) FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.Supplier,C.ReferenceID,C.Description
ORDER BY C.Supplier
```